# Transform and Transition not working with each other in CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform

I have looked into other stack overflow answers but either I don't really understand them or they are providing different workarounds for a quite different problem. In my case, transitions are working with every other property except for transform.

```css
.container {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 70px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  left: 40%;
  transition: all 10ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.button {
  background-color: red;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 70px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 8%;
}

.switch {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 3%;
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(.3, -0.77, .6, 1.72) 0ms;
}

.container:hover .button .switch {
  transform: translate(135%);
  background-color: rgb(59, 59, 59);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="switch"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am a beginner and wanna understand if I am doing one or more things wrong here

Comment: What is the expected outcome? It looks like the black circle moves to the right. However, the main issue would be you need to have a **starting** value for `transform` - the non-hovered value. Something like `transform: translate(0)` on the `.switch` styles.

Answer (score -1):

One way I found that you can do what you're asking is by adding these two lines of code

```
transform: translate(0);
transition: transform 3s ease;
```

in your CSS in your switch class. In this case, your CSS code would look something like this:

```
.container {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 70px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  left: 40%;
  transition: all 10ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.button {
  background-color: red;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 70px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 8%;
}

.switch {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 3%;
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(.3, -0.77, .6, 1.72) 0ms;
  transform: translate(0);
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}

.container:hover .button .switch {
  transform: translate(135%);
  background-color: rgb(59, 59, 59);
}
```

This way, you are declaring the transform value before and after the item is not hovered, since the transform property doesn't have a default value, nor does it inherit it from some parent element, therefore it doesn't have a starting value, from which it can transition to the next.